# Is it possible to have a ternary operator, if,if/else statement and switch statement on 1 src code in Java?

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement, conditional-operator

I tried all 4 on 1 src code and my program stops half way through.

here's the code, what did I do wrong?:

```
/*
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
 */

package com.operators;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Casner
 */
public class Operators {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner type = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Welcome to Chip and Burger Joint, would you like to order? please type Yes or No: ");
        String st = type.nextLine();
        String b = "You are now leaving Chip and Burger Joint";
        String c = "Start your order: " ;
        String ord = "Yes".equals(st)? c:b;
        System.out.println(ord);
                
        if(ord.equals(c)){
            
            System.out.print("You have 3 options: 1. Chips only, 2. Burger only, 3. Meal, Please Choose: ");
            int ord1 = type.nextInt();
             
            if(ord1 == 1){
                System.out.print("Please enter MM for mini, S for small, M for medium and L for large: ");
                String chips = type.nextLine();
                
                switch(chips){
                    case "MM": System.out.println("You picked mini chips");
                    break;
                    case "S": System.out.println("You picked small chips");
                    break;
                    case "M": System.out.println("You picked medium chips");
                    break;
                    case "L": System.out.println("You picked large chips");
                    break;
                    default: System.out.println("Thank you!");
                }
            }
            
            else if(ord1 == 2){
                System.out.print("Please enter C for Chicken burger or B for Beef burger: ");
                String burger = type.nextLine();
                switch(burger){
                    case "C": System.out.println("You picked Chicken burger");
                    break;
                    case "B": System.out.println("You picked Beef burger");
                    default: System.out.println("Thank you!");
                }
            }
            
            else if(ord1 == 3){
                System.out.println("Please enter CM for chicken burger meal or BM for beef burger meal");
                String bm = type.nextLine();
                
                switch(bm){
                    case "CM": System.out.println("You picked Chicken burger meal");
                    break;
                    case "BM": System.out.println("You picked Beef burger meal");
                    break;
                    default: System.out.println("Thank you!");
                }
            }
            else System.out.println("Thank You!");
        }
        
        //System.out.println("Thank you!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes of course it is possible. Looking at your code it seems like you are calling `nextInt()` followed by `nextLine()`. So the problem you are experiencing is likely [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Comment: Yes, that's possible. If you'd like to know what your code is actually doint at runtime, you should use the debugger that's included in your IDE.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Obviously the code using Scanner should not part of a minimal example about if and switch. If it part of the issue then you made the wrong question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)